# git push wrong repository

Tags: git, hook, push

We currently have two repositories.  Repository A is about 100M.  Repository B is about 3G.
We had a situation where a developer of repo B configured a remote that points to repo A and pushed a branch (call it repo_B_branch) to repo A.

Now this increased the size of repo A to 3G+.  Not good.

Repo A has receive.denynonfastforward set to true.  Shouldn't this have denied the creation of repo_B_branch on repo A?  Shouldn't git prevent push of branches that don't share a common ancestor with master?

Comment: Do they both have the same 'blank' root commit?

Comment: Nope they do not share the same room commit.  I'm not sure what you mean by 'blank' though.  Files added in repoA's root commit and repoB's root commit are completely different.

Comment: If the sha1 at the very root of the DAG, because of some corporate manate, ended up being identical, e.g. they cloned/copied an empty repo (with initial commit holding corporate IPR and licence file), then all repos your would be able to link into any other....

Comment: My other thought is that it is treated as an orphan branch, but I haven't looked into the issues involved in that.

Comment: I think to avoid this, you might need to add a pre-receive hook on the server to deny these pushes. Don't think this is configurable by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`denynonfastforward` prevents replacing an existing branch with a new version of the branch that does not have the existing branch history in it. If the developer pushed a branch that did not already exist in the repository, making it a "new" branch, then it would not be denied, regardless of whether or not it had common ancestors with anything else in the repository (if it had no common ancestry, then it gets created as an orphan or disconnected branch).

Comment: Yes, this was the case.  The user pushed a new branch.  Is there an option to prevent such pushes from happening?

Comment: Not that I know of, short of writing hooks to inspect what is being pushed before accepting it (the update or post-update hooks).